# How to remove shadow of image on matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image: How to obtain a fruit without shadow?]

As you can see in image, I isolate objects using Otsu method, but shadows make the result innacurate. How to isolate object without shadow?

Comment: A simple idea is to distinguish by colour components. For example, convert from RGB to HSV. Shadows are grey (low S), objects hopefully not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I = imread('YgmAf.jpg');  % your original image
imagesc(I)

I=rgb2hsv(I);
I1=I(:,:,2);   % change to hsv and select the channel with most clear contrast between object and shadow

thresholded = I1 > 0.23; %% Threshold to isolate lungs
thresholded = bwareaopen(thresholded,100);  % remove too small pixels
I2=thresholded.*I1;
I3=edge(I2,'canny',graythresh(I2));  % ostu method
I3 = imfill(I3,'hole');
figure,imagesc(I3)  %object binary image
```

Result image:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution, this work when the edge connected. but in my dataset, the edge not connected perfectly. But i'll develop this code for may dataset. thanks