# Remove shadow under image

Tags: matlab

I have used the following code to obtain a border of the image and also remove the shadow under the image.The image is a grayscale image.
The code is:

```
x = imread('image.jpg');
sobel_h = [-1 0 1;-2 0 2;-1 0 1];
sobel_v = [-1 0 1;-2 0 2;-1 0 1]';
x_sobel_h = conv2(x,sobel_h,'same');
x_sobel_v = conv2(x,sobel_v,'same');
x_sobel_c = sqrt((x_sobel_h).^2+(x_sobel_v).^2);
x_sobel_c=uint8(x_sobel_c);
figure,imshow(x_sobel_c);
z=x_sobel_c;
z(z~=0 & z<=150)=0;
z(z>0)=255;
figure,imshow(z);
```

I found this code on Matlab File Exchange.It is simple and works well with some images but the shadow remains in some images.

The shadow can be removed if I change `z<=150` to a higher value.But depending on the image, this value needs to be changed.Does anyone know some other thresholding method to remove the shadow in different images? If anyone can point me to any kind of reference material, I would be grateful.Thank you

Comment: It is **impossible** to use a constant threshold that would work for all images.

Comment: Then can you please suggest any other method that I can use to obtain better results?

Comment: You need to do your code for your case. First rule of image processing: It is  **IMPOSIBLE** that any algorithm will work correctly in all images.

Comment: I know.I have gone through many papers on removing shadows and implemented the codes for some but none seem to work well.I don't want it to work for all images or work perfectly.I just wanted to know some suggestions that will help me head in the right direction

Comment: The variable `x` is not defined in your code.  Does `x=I`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.I changed it

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there will be no magic bullet for removing the shadows.

The closest you will probably be able to come is to use a dynamic method to determine the optimal threshold for each image.  For example, Otsu's method is implemented in MATLAB, through the commands `graythresh` and `multithresh` (the former defines one threshold to divide the image into 2 classes, the latter allows you to specify the number of thresholds).

Comment: Thank you.I have used these functions while coding but I didn't give them much importance since I did not know if I was using the right functions.But now I will concentrate on them more and modify my code.I have also gone through the question in this link which implements Otsu's method and it is very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331347/how-to-remove-shadow-of-image-on-matlab